# Как заменить синхронный XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Чем заменить синхронный запрос?
Нужно загрузить данные для последующего использования в "глобальные" переменные `one` и `two` до того, как подключится скрипт `main.js` (внизу кода). При этом по окончанию загрузки страницы (включая переменные!) должен выполнится некий код.

Сейчас я это реализую методом синхронных запросов. Но: а) браузер кричит о нежелательности такого метода; б) в момент загрузки страница зависает, что непозволяет проигрываться анимации загрузки.

```
<html>
<div id="loading">LOADING. ANIMATION</div>
<div id="app" style="display:none">my site</div>
</html>

<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', "dir/one.html", false);
xhr.send();
var one = xhr.responseText;

xhr.open('GET', "dir/two.html", false);
xhr.send();
var two = xhr.responseText;

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('app').style.display = "block";
};
</script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: _Чем заменить синхронный запрос?_ - асинхронным

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю, что в этом случае страница не будет ждать его загрузки (и будет ещё до её завершения подгружаться main.js и выполнятся код onload). И при синхронном запросе, как я понимаю, нельзя получить данные в «глобальную» переменную вне функции запроса.

Comment: переписать main.js что бы он мог дождаться данных, прежде чем выполнять какие-то действия.

Comment: код onload - выполняется когда происходит событие onload